# Install with external disk drive

Tags: boot, system-installation

I partitioned my hard drive, and downloaded Ubuntu, and put it on a disk. My computers disk drive does not work, so I can't boot it via disk drive.

My only options for booting are these:

> - HDD
> - LAN
> - FDD
> - CD/ROM
> - USB Memory

I have searched Google for this, but I can't find anything, and the only thing that shows up is external hard drive.

Is there any way I can install it from my external disk drive?

Comment: Does you External Hard Drive connect via a USB cable?

Comment: @MikeKoch Yes it does. It is connected via a usb cable into my usb port.

Comment: Have you tried using `USB Memory` as your boot device? I'm not sure what kind of computer you have, but sometimes the BIOS will boot USB drives through that option. Make sure that your external HD has been properly formatted to be used as a bootable drive. (If you need to convert your external HD to be bootable, you can use Unetbootin, available at http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/‎)

Comment: @MikeKoch No I have not tried that. I'll try it, and let you know what I find.

Comment: @MikeKoch I just tried that, and it didn't work. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Wait. Is this an external CD drive or an external hard drive?

Comment: @MikeKoch I'll try that. I'm working on downloading it right now. I'll let you know if that worked.

Comment: Wait. Is this an external CD drive or an external hard drive?

Comment: @MikeKoch It is an external ***Disk*** drive not hard drive

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12795/discussion-between-dozer789-and-mike-koch)

Answer (score 1):

You can't install Ubuntu on a Floppy or CDRom drive.  The floppy is too small.  The CDRom isn't read/writable.

You can, however, install on a USB/Pen drive.  The install will go the same way as it would on your hard drive.  Just specify the pen drive as the install partition "/" of the pen drive.

Comment: This is all good, except I don't have a USB Memory Stick...

Comment: I was referring to the options you mentioned in your message.  USB Memory Stick is another name (or equivalent resource) of USB Memory.  Take a look at: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick .

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Universal USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) for your needs.

Comment: Looks like it might work. I'll test it on monday.

Comment: Dont forget to mention if it worked

Comment: I decided I would just transfer my hard drive over to another computer that is the same. Thanks for your help though!